# Load jquery script based on CSS media query

Tags: jquery

**Present behavior:** All links on mobile version, loading in new window. But, desktop version works fine. Tried using "_self", not working.

**Expected behavior:** Mobile links have to open in same window and it should not affect other lightbox or popup behavior. Also, desktop version.

Is there a way to target links to stop propagation or return false if `@media screen and (max-width: 767px)`?

If I use e.stopPropgation() or return false, it affects my desktop version links and lightbox and all other trigger action by redirect to "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your compatibility needs, one solution would be to use [window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia)

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  /* the view port is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
  /* the view port is less than 400 pixels wide */ 
  $('.your-link-class').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
   alert('Less than 768');
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks... after add this condition, still some links redirecting as "undefined" url.. not sure.. why its happening?

Comment: can you put a link to youre page? or sourece to jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Below code only causing the issue on mobile. 

if ($(window).width() < 768) {
       $(document).on("click", "a", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            if(!$(event.target).attr("href")){
            location.href = $(event.target).parent().attr("href");
            }
            else{
            location.href = $(event.target).attr("href");
            }
  });

        $('.navigation-primary--mobile__menu>a, .modal-profiler .status-item>a').click(function(e) { 
             e.stopPropagation();
             e.preventDefault();
        });
    }

Comment: Links are opening in new window only on CQ environment. HTML version works fine without these additional codes. Thanks for your great help.